# How to use Color-Thief.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm a newbie with this (very interesting) script, and I'm trying to find out how to use it.

On its GitHub site, it says:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
```

But what is sourceImage? A link to the image? A jQuery object of the image (like $("img") )? Or what?

It would be nice if someone can create a fiddle so I can see the code in action.

PS: I also tried to look in the source of [its website](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/), but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: From the plugin's source code, it's simply an [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) instance.

Comment: You could have just tried...

Comment: Have you tried it to see what it does? Try experimenting before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [author's blog](http://lokeshdhakar.com/color-thief/) has this example:

```
myImage = $('#myImage');
dominantColor = getDominantColor(myImage);
paletteArray = createPalette(myImage, 10); // 2nd argument sets # of colors in palette
```

The article is old, so the code is no more the same, but I assume that `sourceImage` in your example is the same as `myImage` in this case.

Also, from the code of the demo:

```
$('.run-functions-button').on('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text('...');
    var $imageSection = $this.closest('.image-section');
    var $colorThiefOutput = $imageSection.find('.color-thief-output');
    var $targetimage = $imageSection.find('.target-image');
    showColorsForImage($targetimage, $imageSection);
  });
```

`.run-functions-button` are the "TAP" yellow buttons.
It retrieves the closes `image-section`, and the `target-image` inside. Then it calls `showColorsForImage($targetImage, $imageSection)`.

In `showColorsForImage` there is this line:

`colorThief.getColor(image)`. So I'm pretty sure it's an image object, as Frèdèric already pointed out in his comment.

Comment: The first example is either outdated or plain wrong: `getDominantColor()` takes a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so `myImage[0]` should be passed instead of `myImage`.

Comment: The example is old, and I wrote it in my answer ("the code is no more the same"). The point was the first line, `myImage = $('#myImage')`.

Answer (score 0):

`sourceImage` is a reference to an already declared image.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin His question was "But what is sourceImage?" So I explained what it is.